# Stretchable ScrollView (like HTC sense UI)

Tags: android, scrollview

Have you seen stretchable scrolls in HTC sense? When you scroll up to last and still try to scroll it, it scratches and goes back to original state.

How to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 0):

Elastic.java

import *.java.elasticity.*